# ListView with Switch (boolean) Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, boolean

How can I implement boolean listener I have a custom listView with image, text and boolean but I cant figure out how to set boolean listener. Here are some pictures:
[image]

I already have fullscreen code and it works perfect but only when I click on the Fullscreen text not the Switch. Any idea for the Switch listener?

Here is the customview class

```
public CustomListViewImageTextText(Activity context, String[]web, String[]web2, Integer[] imageId,boolean[] isChecked){
    super(context, R.layout.custom_item_listview_image_text_text, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.web2 = web2;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}

@Override
public View getView ( int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_item_listview_image_text_text, null, true);

    txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subText);
    imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    mySwitch = (SwitchCompat) rowView.findViewById(R.id.newswitch);

    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(web2[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    mySwitch.setChecked(isChecked[position]);

    if (position != 2) {
        mySwitch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

And here is the part of the Settings

```
CustomListViewImageTextText adapter = new CustomListViewImageTextText(SettingsActivity.this, settingsArray, settingsArray2, imageId, isChecked);
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
})
```

Comment: Your code looks like you are using a custom adapter. You could achieve the same layout with a PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get this event like this. You are initializing switch in onItemClick so it will not trigger at that time.
If you want to get check change event in your activity then you have make on static method. So that you can call that method from adapter when the switch state change.

Make this method in your activity:

```
public static isChecked(boolean flag){ 
     Log.i("TAG,"isChecked:"+flag); 
}
```

and add below code to your getView method of adapter:

```
mySwitch = (SwitchCompat) rowView.findViewById(R.id.newswitch); 
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { 
    <your_activity_name>.isChecked(isChecked); 
    } 
});
```

> Note: Make sure it will not be helpful if there are more than one
>   switches available in listview. For that you have to make few changes by passing
>   boolean as well as int(as an index value) to **isCheckd** method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);
        sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //Insert your logic here
            }
        });
```

Comment: I cant do that because I am accesing the custom listview from other listview class. :(

Comment: can you explain this further? Or edit the post with the explanation?

Comment: I have SettingsActivity class that handles the listview items and a CustomListView class which has the custom listview in it. In SettingsActiviy I set the adapter to the CustomListView class.

Comment: and you can't use this because?

Comment: I added the classes go see them. I cant make reference to the switch.

Comment: you can by making a reference in the last method of your post, just search it like this `view.findViewById(R.id.yourSwitch)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106159/discussion-between-vucko-and-chaos).

Answer (score 0):

First use List method item on click listener to get the item clicked, then identify that the third item with some value assigned or tag assigned (Full screen is clicked), change the state of the switch or do some work on it